# How to minimize and maximize with word problems?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have two different types of problems that I'm having trouble figuring out:

1) A rancher wants to fence in a rectangular area of $18,200$ ft$^2$ in a field and then divide the region in half with a fence down the middle parallel to one side. What is the smallest length of fencing that will be required to do this?

2) If a total of $1,600$ cm$^2$ of material is to be used to make a box with a square base and an open top, find the largest possible volume of such a box.

Comment: I'm sorry I've got number wrong on both of the questions. For one it should be 18200 and for 2 it should be 1600. For 1 I got answers of 110.1514 for x and 165.2271 for y. For question 2 I got 987/2. I'm not sure exactly how to do the problems and can't find where I'm going wrong.

Comment: So the 36,400 in #1 should be 18,200 and the 3,200 in #2 should be 1,600?

Comment: Yes sorry. I was trying to figure out the problem and wrote them down wrong without looking at the page.

Comment: Are you supposed to use a single-variable approach or a two-variable approach?

Comment: I believe a two variable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1:

First note that if the whole rectangular region has an area of $18,200$, then each half will have an area of $9,100$.

[image: Rancher's Field]

We want to minimize the perimeter of the whole rectangular region, i.e. minimize $P=4x+3y$ subject to the constraint $xy=9,100$.

Applying Lagrange Multipliers gives $$4=\lambda y$$ $$3=\lambda x$$

and after solving for $\lambda$ and equating equations, we get $$y=\frac{4}{3}x$$

Back-substituting into the original constraint $xy=9,100$ gives $\frac{4}{3}x^2=9,100$, or $x=5\sqrt{273}\approx82.6136$ ft$^2$. Therefore $y=\frac{20\sqrt{273}}{3}\approx110.1514$ ft$^2$.

Problem #2:

[image: Box]

The task for this problem is to maximize $V=x^2y$ subject to the constraint $SA=1,600=x^2+4xy$.

Applying Lagrange Multipliers gives $$2xy=\lambda (2x+4y)$$ $$x^2=\lambda 4x$$

Since the edge length cannot be $0$, we can solve the equations for $\lambda$ and equate them. $$\frac{xy}{x+2y}=\frac{x}{4}$$ $$4xy=x^2+2xy$$ $$x=2y$$

Back-substituting into the constraint gives $4y^2+8y^2=1,600$, or $y=\frac{20\sqrt{3}}{3}\approx11.5470$ cm$^2$. Thus $x=\frac{40\sqrt{3}}{3}\approx23.0940$ cm$^2$. As a result, the maximum volume is $V=\frac{32,000\sqrt{3}}{9}\approx6,158.4029$ cm$^2$.